# Buttons not visible on the application. What's wrong?

Tags: android, android-studio

I created an empty activity for 'My Testing App' and it looks like the following in the preview section:

[image: The Preview tab screenshot.]

But when I generated a build apk and used the same in my cell phone the result was like the following:

[image: A screenshot of my cell phone.]

I can only view the exit button on the very top left but the two other buttons, that should be above it are **missing.**
I tried to rearrange the icons on the screen as well. I made them to go to the bottom, to the right most, but I see no change when the apk is reinstalled.

**How do I make them visible on the hardware?**

Here is the snap of the code for this activity:

[image]

Comment: Please share the relevant layout with us, else we can't really help.

Comment: I've added the code. @CarstenHagemann

Comment: Pls share your manifest and the java and layout file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quickly add constraints to your layout just click on the **Infer Constraints** [image] button in the Layout Editor toolbar. Learn more about the feature here: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#use-autoconnect-and-infer-constraints

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on you Layout and select "Convert View" Option.
then select "LinearLayout" Option.
it will show all three buttons in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn about ConstrainLayout in Android

View in ConstrainLayout is not only drag and drop. You should link the constrain line in each view to reference with somewhere on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any XML attributes prefixed with `tools` are removed when the app is compiled and are **only** rendered by Android Studio layout editor.

You need to properly set constraints in your `ConstraintLayout`, not use absolute positioning.

Or you may instead use RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Start by reading this. Most of what you need is answered here. The problem is that your views are not properly constrained (basically they aren't linked to anything so when you run your app it doesn't know where to place them and just defaults to the upper left).