# Android Studio - Why all controls are all in upper left

Tags: android

Why all my controls(buttons, textfields) are all in upper left of my emulator when I test run it?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, first of all this is not the proper way to ask a question, I invite you to take a look at [SO help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), secondly please post your XML code so we can provide you the needed help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buttons not visible on the application. What's wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017289/buttons-not-visible-on-the-application-whats-wrong)

Comment: this is not the proper way to ask a question

Answer (score 3):

When you first add `widgets` to your **App**, it automatically goes to the *Top-Left* of the screen. Try adding some `Constraints` to your `widgets`.

To make a `View` position in the center of your *App*, add these lines of code to the bottom of a `widget` in your XML:

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
```

**Example**:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your views are not setup up correctly in your layout. First of all, if you could give the code for your layout (`activity_main.xml` or something similar) it will be easier to solve your problem.

The likely culprit is either that you are using a `RelativeLayout` and haven't set the view to be in relative position to another or, more likely, that you are using a `ConstraintLayout` and haven't linked your views correctly.

If you are using constraint layout the easiest way to link your views is from the Design tab, looking at the UI of your app. Click your `TextView`/`EditText`/etc and drag from the little squares that appear on the sides to literally link to either the side of the screen or to another view.

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like you may be using a constraintLayout.  Make sure that in your layout you have a vertical and horizontal constraint set on each control.